# Is this "Shadetouched" homebrew race balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, homebrew-review

Designed to be a Shadowfell counterpart to the [Faetouched](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153709/is-this-faetouched-homebrew-race-balanced) race, this race is humans/half-humans or descendants of humans/half-humans who stayed in the Shadowfell to long.

> ## Shadetouched
>
> **Ability Score Increase.** Your Dexterity, Constitution, and Charisma
> scores all increase by 1.
>
> **Age.** Shadetouched show no physical signs of aging, but usually live
> around 200 years.
>
> **Alignment.** Shadetouched are usually neutral.
>
> **Size.** Shadetouched are about the same size as humans. Your size is
> Medium.
>
> **Speed.** Your base walking speed is 30 feet.
>
> **Darkvision.** Used to the gloomy darkness of the Shadowfell, you have
> darkvision with a range of 120 feet.
>
> **Dark Resilience.** You have resistance to necrotic and psychic damage.
>
> **Shadow Stealth.** You are proficient in Stealth. In addition you have
> advantage on Dexterity (Stealth) checks when in dim light or darkness.
>
> **Shadow Weaver.** You know the Toll the Dead cantrip. When you reach 3rd
> level, you can cast the Shadow Blade spell once with this trait and
> regain the ability to do so when you finish a long rest. When you
> reach 5th level, you can cast the Darkness spell once with this trait
> and regain the ability to do so when you finish a long rest. Charisma
> is your spellcasting ability for these spells.
>
> **Sunlight Sensitivity.** You have disadvantage on attack rolls and on
> Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight when you, the target of
> your attack, or whatever you are trying to perceive is in direct
> sunlight.
>
> **Languages.** you can speak, read, and write Common and one language of
> your choice.

Is this homebrew race balanced?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## On the stronger side but fairly balanced

I'm going to use [Detect Balance](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vq1kz6PRAbw5LHy6amH-bNb4OuB8DBXL1RsZROt03Sc/edit#gid=1146257777) to assess how powerful this race is. This tool assigns scores to various racial features based on how useful they are. A good homebrew race should score between 24 and 27 and should never exceed 30. Here's how the calculation comes out for your race:

[image]

With a score of 29 your race is among the strongest of the existing races but certainly not overpowered.

There is one issue with this calculation however. I used "Standard Delayed Magic" to estimate the power of your *Shadow Weaver* ability, normally this would be a cantrip at first level, a 1st level spell at third level and a 2nd level spell at fifth level. [*Shadow Blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shadow-blade) is a 2nd level spell which makes this slightly stronger than it should be. You should likely replace this with a first level spell, though I can understand the desire to use this one.

This race seems to have strong thematics and abilities that work well together. It has a lot of similarities to the Elf (Drow) race and is fairly balanced with it (Drow scores 27 on detect balance). I commend you for such a well thought out class. Go ahead and playtest this.